# Laravel CRUD - Update doesn't work - doesn't make changes

Tags: php, laravel

Everything works great in CRUD, except for update.

My Controller:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->update($request->all()); 
    return redirect('/posts');
}
```

Comment: tried to call `$post->save()` before `return`? also do make sure that `$request->all()` fields matches with the one you set as `$fillable` in the model.

Comment: Can you dd what you get from $request->all(); so that you can know what is coming and if it tallies with what you expect in the database

Comment: try to dd($request->all()) to see if data is present, else check if your fields are fillable on the model as the update function uses a ->fill() call

Comment: Guys I solved it by adding 'title' in $fillable in my Post model

Answer (score 1):

To answer this you need to know if that id is coming through properly.
Do a dump($id);  This will show you if it's null or something unexpected.
I'd then wrap the $post in logic to rule out nulls or bad data.
Technically if you are doing a post from the front your id will usually be

`$request->id` this being sent from a hidden input on the front.

I'd also use a first() because everything coming to this function should already be created and not be null since you're populating this from the database.

```
$post = Post::where('id',  $request->id)->first();
```

Next do a dump on $post `dump($post);` this will show you the post info.
If you don't have any post info you have trouble and will require more troubleshooting.
Then you can just do your save process, I personally like to to do a 1 to 1 save to make sure all values from the request are being properly handled. So it would be..

```
$post->column_name = $request->input_name;
$post->save();
return back()->with ('status', 'Record Updated!');
```

Then on the front you can display that status from session to show it was updated.
**One caveat using mass update is that you should make sure that the fields you are updating are fillable in the model.**

Comment: If you're doing this approach, i.e. `$post->column_name = ...`, followed by `$post->save()`, then `column_name` _does not_ need to be in the `protected $fillable` array. That's only for `Post::create()` and `Post::update()` methods, i.e. "mass update" methods. This answer "works", but `->update()` is generally recommended as it is less verbose and requires less maintenance.

Comment: @tim true but working with a team of developers I've found that a lot of the front-end folks just name stuff any old willy nilly way.  If inputs aren't named like the columns it will fail.  That's why I always check what's coming through and do a one to one.

Comment: Indeed, that is a fair point. There's ways around that to still use the `update()` method, like `$request->merge(['correct_column_name' => $request->input('willy_nilly_name')])`, then `$post->update($request->input())`, etc., or having a proper PR/QA process, etc. My main point was addressing your bolded point re: `fillable`; that isn't necessary with  your answer  Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I thought I put mass update in the caveat.  I've updated post. Cheers!

Comment: Guys I solved it by adding 'title' in $fillable in my Post model

Comment: @Dzoni Instead of adding that comment multiple times, how about you post your own answer to show that? Stackoverflow is a QA site, questions can have multiple answers, including one written by the question author.

Answer (score 0):

You need check your model at the first it should be something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Crud extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'lastame', 'id',
       ];
}
```

then you have to use

```
dd('$post')
```

to see what you have then you can create your update like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->update($request->all()); 
    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Data is successfully updated');;
}
```